# Convert array to multiline based on keys in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there any way in PhpStorm to convert string

```
$arr = array('where' => '{"key_4":' . $this->key_4 . '}', 'key_2' => $this->user->key_2, 'key_3' => $this->user->key_5, 'key_6' => '');
```

into

```
$arr = array(
    'where' => '{"key_4":' . $this->key_4 .'}',
    'key_2' => $this->user->key_2, 
    'key_3' => $this->user->key_5, 
    'key_6' => ''
);
```

Has anyone some ideas?

Comment: You may configure your Code Style to do such array formatting -- see array declaration settings. But if question was "is there such action that would do that without touching code style" -- nope.

Comment: @LazyOne what options I need to change in code style? PhpStorm doesn't reformat code to multiline by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+L`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the only changes that I've done in **Default** scheme to get such formatting:

[image]

Results (before and after):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I waste over 30 minutes by searching myself